# Hard square root and binary representation question

Tags: number-theory

If $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ is representend in binary the value is $0.10110101000001...$ How can we represent the number above after inserting a zero between each digit ($0.1000101000100010000000000010$) with a formula (function)? (this formula should contain decimals constans)

EDIT: If such formula (function) doesn't exist, how to prove it?

Comment: Why would you think such a "formula" exists?

Comment: I will edit that. But if such formula doesn't exist. Is there a way to prove that?

Comment: What is your definition of a formula

Comment: I mean a function.

Answer (score 2):

For any $a \in [0,1)$, we can define a unique analytic function $f_{a}(z)$ (over at least the open unit disk) by
$$
f_{a}(z)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_{i}z^{i},
$$
where the binary representation of $a$ is $0.a_0a_1a_2...$  Then $(1/2)f_{a}(1/2)=a$, and $(1/4)f_{a}(1/4)$ is equal to the "spaced out" version of $a$ that you described.  Of course, finding any other representation of $f_{1/\sqrt{2}}$ then becomes the trick.